# Распарсить сайт

Tags: python, парсер

Не получается распарсить сайт http://www.championat.com/news/football/1.html для получения ссылки на каждую новость в словарь. Может кто-то делал это? С помощью Beautiful soup не получилось, сложноватый html для меня, может есть у кого какие идеи?

Comment: Не хватает примеров кода и объяснения мест, в которых не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно брать новости, то может быть лучше не из html их парсить, а из RSS-ленты? Там структура простая и ясная.

http://www.championat.com/xml/rss_football.xml